# select value in spinner and pass id of that value to server in android

Tags: android

I have got list of "client_id' and "organization" from JSON response and need to passe these organization list to spinner , but when user select organization name from spinner then need to pass client_id associated with that organization to server.

here is my code .

```
   try {

      //*** Getting Array of Attributes
            attributes = jsonreturn.getJSONObject(TAG_ATTRIBUTE);
            String status = attributes.getString(TAG_VALIDCODE);
            JSONObject clients = jsonreturn.getJSONObject(TAG_CLIENTS);
            JSONArray client = clients.getJSONArray(TAG_CLIENT);

            final String[] list_client_id = new String[client.length()+1];
            list_client_id[0]= "Select Client";
            final String[] list_client_name = new String[client.length()];

       if(status.equals("200")){

     for(int i = 0; i < client.length(); i++)

         {
            JSONObject clientlist = client.getJSONObject(i);

     //***** Storing each JSON item in variable
             String client_id = clientlist.getString(TAG_CLIENT_ID);
             String organization = clientlist.getString(TAG_ORGANIZATION);



          list_client_id[i+1]= clientlist.getString(TAG_CLIENT_ID);
          list_client_name[i]= clientlist.getString(TAG_ORGANIZATION);
         }
       }

       else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Invalid Details", 1000).show();       }

        ClientNameSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.ClientId);



        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list_client_name);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        ClientNameSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

       /* ArrayAdapter<String> adapterid = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list_client_id);
        adapterid.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        ClientNameSpinner.setAdapter(adapterid);*/

}
            catch (JSONException e)
            {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Instead of using two different string array for list_client_id and list_client_name use only Custom Object ListArray which contains both together and pass it to your spinner. SO on click spinner item you get related client id over their.

Comment: @user370305 i have no idea about Custom Object ListArray .. please help me , suggest some resources if you know.

Comment: Look at http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429&q=customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapterr and http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/ and http://www.josecgomez.com/2010/05/03/android-putting-custom-objects-in-listview/

Answer (score 0):

```
ClientNameSpinner .setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
        // 
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
        // 

    }

});
```